# .NET Core web app won't run in Docker container

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core-2.0

I have a vanilla .NET Core 2 web app that I setup in JetBrains Rider and I immediately started working on a Docker environment for it. I followed this guide to get started:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/dotnetcore/

I altered it slightly to come up with this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest AS packager

RUN mkdir -p /opt/build
WORKDIR /opt/build

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o bin

# --

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:runtime AS runtime

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY --from=packager /opt/build/bin/. .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/opt/app/aspnetapp.dll"]
```

The image builds and when I go to run the container I get the following output:

```
dan@mycomputer ~/Desktop/coreapi (master)
$ docker build -t myapp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  25.09kB
Step 1/12 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest AS packager
 ---> e1a56dca783e
Step 2/12 : RUN mkdir -p /opt/build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 95f9c936d0d1
Step 3/12 : WORKDIR /opt/build
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 64f26c356fd7
Step 4/12 : COPY *.csproj .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 38a2fb7ca6bb
Step 5/12 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 70dbc44d98ae
Step 6/12 : COPY . .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b1019d53a861
Step 7/12 : RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o bin
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 8e112606633a
Step 8/12 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:runtime AS runtime
 ---> cc240a7fd027
Step 9/12 : RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 954f494febc4
Step 10/12 : WORKDIR /opt/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b74be941e7dc
Step 11/12 : COPY --from=packager /opt/build/bin/. .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4c229192d99b
Step 12/12 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/opt/app/aspnetapp.dll"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> fb6ef4015fba
Successfully built fb6ef4015fba
Successfully tagged myapp:latest
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.

dan@mycomputer ~/Desktop/coreapi (master)
$ docker run -p 5001:5001 myapp:latest
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
```

The app doesn't run and I get a message that says I need to install the SDK. What's up with that? Shouldn't the runtime Docker image have everything neede to run the app?

Comment: Just a wild guess but maybe try replacing FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest AS packager with FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS packager

Comment: That's what I had originally and that didn't work either. I tried the vanilla image by itself before making any customizations and it also didn't work. Also, the binary appears to build in `packager` but when the last line `ENTRYPOINT` executes the container doesn't appear to have the necessary runtime files to run the executable.

Comment: Maybe without the AS runtime? On the second part?

Comment: Btw the names ARE case sensitive so make sure the dll being build is really aspnetapp.dll and not something like AspNetApp.dll

Comment: As I mentioned shortly ago, I tried it vanilla so it didn't have that already when first run, right? Also that doesn't affect anything. The error does not say it can't find the binary it says it can't find the runtime/sdk. Thanks for trying but I'm looking for someone that has a lot of experience working on this versus random guesses. If you'd like to spin up the test environment I specified above and try it yourself and come back with actual results, by all means. Otherwise these ideas aren't very helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: You docker file is pretty simple not rocket sience. I saw this https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/issues/322 which looked pretty similar to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution by modifying the `ENTRYPOINT` to run `tail -f /dev/null`. From there, I entered the container and saw that the name of the binary adjusts based on your project name which the Docker documentation didn't make clear to me.

I also updated my base images and this solved my problem. Here is my latest Dockerfile below:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS packager

RUN mkdir -p /opt/build
WORKDIR /opt/build

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o bin

# --

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS runtime

RUN mkdir -p /opt/app
WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY --from=packager /opt/build/bin/. .

EXPOSE 80

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/opt/app/coreapi.dll"]
```